# Need to get application name while fetching logcat in Android App

Tags: android, android-logcat

I try the below code to read device's Log. Is there any way to identify the application name from the Logs so that I can record application specific Log.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d *:E");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new                
    InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logcat will record `pid`, and `pid` refers to application name.
You may use `ps` or other command to get relation between `pid` and application name.

Comment: when an application force close,i read this error on logs , but due to force close of the application system does not provide any application name corresponding to that id.